# Can I free a trapped wild animal on shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, animals

If I find an animal trapped under a box on shabbat, is there anything wrong with letting it out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I have been unable to locate a good copy of the Mishna Berura (316-25) that he quotes, [this document](http://www.cckollel.org/html/parsha/bereishis/Toldos5764.html) does say that there is no issue with freeing a trapped animal.

This is also asserted by the book ["39 Melochos"](http://books.google.com/books?id=vL3DYf61OK8C&pg=PA884&lpg=PA884&source=bl&ots=ivOBGRVCu4&sig=3x_ROtxE58oSv5LsNFSRwMqROWs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UPsCUPmFE4bn0QGy0qjlBw&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=172&f=false). (There's a footnote there, but Google Books won't let me see it.)

This is also stated by ["The Concise Code of Jewish Law"](http://books.google.com/books?id=XGEMTh6xCV4C&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&source=bl&ots=H6IFUP7_eu&sig=kcYCXEwRX4TOnNYw606Mjo0NuMc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UPsCUPmFE4bn0QGy0qjlBw&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=freeing%20trapped%20animal%20shabbos&f=false) with no source. He notes that one should not touch the animal, as it might be muktzeh.

Chabad.org, in a [footnote](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/935211/jewish/Chapter-Ten.htm#footnoteRef100a935211) to the [Rambam's Hilchos Shabbos](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/935211/jewish/Chapter-Ten.htm), brings a Magen Avraham that says (and a Maggid Mishnah that implies) that freeing an animal on Shabbos is completely permitted **provided one does not touch it, since it is muktzeh**.

The [Shulchan Aruch HaRav 316:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25073&st=&pgnum=529) (quoting the above Magid Mishnah and Magen Avraham) states:

> מותר לפתוח הבית בפני הצבי כדי שיברח ויצא וכן צבי שנכנס למצודה מותר
>   לפרקו ממצודתו ובלבד שלא יטלטלנו